# Unable to validate for date in Spring MVC

Tags: validation, date, spring-mvc

I am using custom editors for converting String to date. My code is mentioned below

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    dateFormat.setLenient(false);
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, false));

}
```

When I am entering the date in "yyyy-MM-dd" then its inserting.

But when I am entering blank it throws an exception

> nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not parse date: Unparseable date: " "

I am unable to validate for the same.

If I give some other format the also its not able to parse.

Answer (score 5):

When you instantiate the CustomDateEditor, the second parameter, in your case, should be true.  True allows for empty values.

[CustomDateEditor(SpringSource)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.x/api/org/springframework/beans/propertyeditors/CustomDateEditor.html)